# Хочу прочитать зашифрованный текст в текстовом файле и по значению из словаря codes его расшифровать. Как это сделать?

Tags: python

При чтении из файла зашифрованного текста !@№$%^??* и последующей расшифровки из словаря по значению если буквы повторяются то они печатаются один раз и без пробела. Почему так?

```
codes = {'1': '!', '2': '@', '3': '№', 'h': '%', 'e': '^',
             'l': '?', 'o': '*', 'm': '+', 'y': '/', ' ': '$'}

    file_cod = open(r'E:\Python Project\Tonny Geddis\coding.txt', 'r')
    file = file_cod.read()

    for key, value in codes.items():
        if value in file:
            print(key, end='')
```

Вывод: 123helo

а должно быть 123 hello с пробелом и двумя ll

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант:

```
codes = {'1': '!', '2': '@', '3': '№', 'h': '%', 'e': '^',
             'l': '?', 'o': '*', 'm': '+', 'y': '/', ' ': '$'}
decode = dict(zip(codes.values(), codes.keys()))
file = '!@№$%^??*'
for x in file:
    print(decode[x], end='')
# 123 hello
```

- делаем обратный словарь перекодировки
- идём по тексту файла и раскодируем его через этот обратный словарь

У вас проблема в том, что для расшифровки нужно перебирать символы файла и расшифровывать их по одному через дешифровальную таблицу, а вы вместо этого перебираете шифровальные коды и проверяете, есть ли они в файле. При этом и количество и порядок расшифровываемых символов получаются совсем другими. И то, что расшифрованный текст у вас хоть как-то похож на настоящий объясняется только тем, что в таблице кодировки эти символы идут в том же порядке, что и в шифровке. Но это могло бы быть и не так и у вас бы тогда получилось что-то совсем не похожее, а не только бы повторные символы потерялись.

Answer (score -1):

```
letters = {
    '1': '!', '2': '@', '3': '№', 'h': '%', 'e': '^',
             'l': '?', 'o': '*', 'm': '+', 'y': '/', ' ': '$'
}


class Cryptographer:
    def __init__(self, text=None, path=None):
        self.path = path
        self.text = text

    def encoder(self):
        txt = [letters[i] for i in self.text]

        return "".join(txt)

    def decoder(self):

        decoded_text = []

        for i in self.text:
            for k, v in letters.items():
                if v == i:
                    decoded_text.append(k)

        return "".join(decoded_text)

    def file_encoder(self):
        with open(self.path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:

            txt = [letters[i] for i in f.readline()]

        with open(self.path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:

            f.write("".join(txt))

    def file_decoder(self):

        decoded_text = []

        with open(self.path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:

            for i in f.readline():
                for k, v in letters.items():
                    if v == i:
                        decoded_text.append(k)

        with open(self.path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:

            f.write("".join(decoded_text))

if __name__=="__main__":
    C = Cryptographer(123, "code.txt")
    C.file_encode()
    C.file_decode()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только у мой уровень не позволяет разобраться в коде.